# SQLite handling of NULL

Tags: sqlite, null

I have an SQL query like

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName != 'contents'
```

now contrary to what I expected this does NOT seem to match a colName where its contents is 'NULL'. Looking at [how SQLite handles NULLs](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) and specifially this condition `"null OR true" is true` being true for SqlLite I wouldve thought my query wouldve been sufficent to select the rows with `NULL` for `colName`. I mustve understood this incorrectly. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I can just use

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (colName != 'contents' OR colName IS NULL)
```

but i didnt think i would have to.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get around this issue by using `IS NOT` rather than `!=`.  If you look at [the operators section of this document](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) you'll see:

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true). **It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to evaluate to NULL.** Operators IS and IS NOT have the same precedence as =.

I tested this out myself:

```
sqlite> create table temp( dataColumn, nullColumn );
sqlite> insert into temp( dataColumn, nullColumn ) values ( 'test', NULL );
sqlite> select * from temp where nullColumn != 'test';
sqlite> select * from temp where nullColumn IS NOT 'test';
test|
sqlite> select * from temp where dataColumn IS NOT 'test';
sqlite>
```

From a bit more playing about, it seems that the `!=` operator *will* evaluate to `NULL` when you use it to compare something with `NULL`:

```
sqlite> select ( 'contents' != NULL );

sqlite> select ( 'contents' == NULL );

sqlite> select ( 'contents' IS NULL );
0
sqlite> select ( 'contents' IS NOT NULL );
1
```

Presumably this is why you're not getting the behaviour you expect - you are effectively saying `WHERE NULL != 'contents'` which evaluates to NULL, and doesn't satisfy the WHERE clause

Comment: +1 I don't think there's a thing I could add to that answer which would make it better.